# When do I need u-modifier in PHP regex?

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace, preg-match, pcre

I know, that PHP PCRE functions treat strings as byte sequences, so many sites suggest to use `/u` modifier for handling input and regex as UTF-8.

But, do I really need this always? My tests show, that this flag makes no difference, when I don't use escape sequences or dot or something like this.

For example

`preg_match('/^[\da-f]{40}$/', $string);` to check if string has format of a SHA1 hash

`preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', $spacer, $string);` to replace every char that is non-ASCII letter or number

`preg_replace('/^\+\((.*)\)$/', '\1', $string);` for getting inner content of `+(XYZ)`

These regex contain only single byte ASCII symbols, so it should work on **every** input, regardless of encoding, shouldn't it? Note that third regex uses dot operator, but as I cut off some ASCII chars at beginning and end of string, this should work on UTF-8 also, correct?

Cannot anyone tell me, if I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with the first expression. The characters being quantified are explicitly single-byte, and cannot occur in a UTF-8 multibyte sequence.

The second expression may give you more spacers than you expect; for example:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', "0", "");
// => 0000
```

The third expression also does not pose a problem, as the repeated character is limited by parentheses (which is ASCII-safe).

This is more dangerous:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(.)/', "0", "");
// => 0???
```

Typically, without knowing more about how UTF-8 works, it may be tricky to predict which regexps are safe, and which are not, so using `/u` for all text that might contain a character above U+007F is the best practice.

Comment: But this implies, that I can use `u` modifier only, if I'm absolutely sure, that I handle **user** input? I.e. when matching in binary files, this would fail?

Comment: You typically don't use regexps on non-text data (such as compiled code, zip files or images); and should always use Unicode on text data, unless you have a legacy system that prevents you from doing so, or you have a time-critical system where you can't afford the overhead of multibyte encoding (in which case you would definitely not be using PHP). There's hardly ever any reason in this day and age not to use Unicode.

Comment: One more question: second expression may be not a problem, when discarding chars/bytes (i.e. replacing with empty string when `$spacer = '';`)?

Comment: Yes, the only problem with the second one is that it will replace each byte and not each character. Replacing with nothing makes it a non-issue, as `1 * 0 == 3 * 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode modifier `u` allows proper detection of accented characters, which are always multibyte.

```
preg_match('/([\w ]{2,})/', 'baz báz báž', $match); 
// $match[0] = "baz b" ... wrong, accented/multibyte chars silently ignored

preg_match('/([\w ]{2,})/u', 'baz báz báž', $match); 
// $match[0] = "baz báz báž" ... correct
```

Use it also for safe detection of whitespaces:

```
preg_replace(''/\s+/u', ' ', $txt); // works reliably e.g. with EOLs (line endings)
```

Answer (score 0):

> u (PCRE_UTF8)
>   This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.

You will need this when you have to compare Unicode characters, such as Korean or Japanese.

In other words, unless you are not comparing strings that is not Unicode (such as English), You don't need to use this flag.

Comment: "strings that is not Unicode (such as English)" — "the naïve fiancé likes Häagen-Dazs" :)